# Where is the root name servers (hint servers) file in Windows 8?

Tags: dns

For any DNS resolution agent to resolve a DNS query, it should start with hint files (root name servers).

I can't find this file, or this list in Windows 8. Where is it?

Comment: Hint files are for DNS servers, I don't think Windows 8 has them. You could configure the hosts file I guess. What are you trying to achieve? Use Windows 8 as a DNS server?

Comment: @Kilisi, it's for research purpose. But of course Windows, or essentially any OS, or essentially anything that wants to resolve a DNS resolution request should start from somewhere, a known predefined hard-coded entity. Yeah, it has it. And I've seen the file in previous versions, but I can't find them in Windows 8.

Comment: I've only needed to look at it on servers, I'm looking at a Win XP pro machine now which doesn't have it, or at least not where I'd expect to find it Windows/system32/dns . And a server which does. But I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: `%SystemRoot%\System32\Dns\cache.dns` maybe.

> **For any DNS resolution agent to resolve a DNS query, it should start with hint files (root name servers)**

That isn't true for resolvers on personal computers (not servers). The list of DNS servers to contact was traditionally taken from the resolver configuration. For example /etc/resolv.conf in the case of Unix-like systems, I guess MS-Windows stores this stuff in the registry. These days the list of DNS servers to consult usually comes from the DHCP service. In Windows 7 you can find it in

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\Tcpip\Parameters\DhcpNameServer
```

I upgraded all my Win8 machines to 10 so I can't check if it is the same in Win8. A registry search should locate this quickly.

On a DNS server, the hint file is only needed at start-up, it shouldn't be referred to for every query thereafter. For Windows this [used to be](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735686(v=ws.10).aspx) in a file called `cache.dns` in `%SystemRoot%\System32\Dns`.

Comment: you're right. Yet still the initial clue is important here. Be it on local machine that is stored statically, or on a DHCP server that is pulled on initial configuration, still to resolve a DNS request we need to start from somewhere (from a.root-servers.net for example). I think for subsequent requests, DNS resolver has cached that clue, but it still needs to contact it to start the chain, doesn't it?

Comment: @Seeed: No on desktop/personal PCs the resolver *never* needs to know the *root* DNS servers - only a *nearby* DNS server (usually, but not necessarily, one that is authoritative for the local domain).

Comment: yeah, I understood. In fact, that nearby server should know about another server, which should know about yet another server and so on till someone asks the root servers where is **a.com** for example.

Comment: @Saeed: See http://superuser.com/a/477316/52492