# dnsmasq does not not resolve name

Tags: dnsmasq

I have trouble with **dnsmasq** - it does not resolve directly defined name.

```
$ sudo dnsmasq -d -A /test/172.17.0.2 --log-queries &
dnsmasq: started, version 2.48 cachesize 150
dnsmasq: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-I18N DHCP TFTP "--bind-interfaces with SO_BINDTODEVICE"
dnsmasq: read /etc/hosts - 2 addresses

$ ping test
ping: unknown host test
```

What is wrong?

P.S. `resolv.conf` content:

```
options timeout:2 attempts:5
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search ec2.internal
nameserver 172.31.0.2
```

Comment: Is localhost in your resolv.conf?

Comment: No. Have updated question with resolv.conf content.

Comment: You need to tell your computer to ask itself for DNS first for dnsmasq to work for you.  https://superuser.com/questions/477314/how-do-dns-servers-work