# How does DNS name resolution work?

Tags: dns, nameserver

Could someone point me to a good, comprehensive explanation of how DNS name resolution works? I've seen a few simplified examples where a client connects to the root DNS server ("."), which then sends the client to a DNS server for the next level below ("com"), and then the client continues down the tree like that.

Is that actually how DNS name resolutions works? Wouldn't that mean that each "com" server would have to have NS records for every domain that ends with ".com"? That seems like a lot of domains. Or is the authority for ".com" split among a few different servers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do DNS servers work?](https://superuser.com/questions/477314/how-do-dns-servers-work)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/1061258/113312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that actually how DNS name resolutions works?

It is. DNS *is* a fairly simple system.

> Wouldn't that mean that each "com" server would have to have NS records for every domain that ends with ".com"? That seems like a lot of domains.

It would, but it's not *that* many. Wikipedia says there are ~146 million domains in the `.com` zone, so after some rough calculations (taking the size of NS records for a random domain and multiplying it by 146M), you could probably fit all of the NS and glue records in 32 GB of RAM. That's not much for a server.

(Though the additional DNSSEC records bloat a zone to several times its original size, especially for RSA signatures, but it's still doable – servers with 256 or 512 GB of memory are still well within reasonable range.)

As a practical example, the entire `se` zone of Sweden is freely available [for download](https://internetstiftelsen.se/en/domains/tech-tools/access-to-zonefiles-for-se-and-nu/). It has around 1.4 million domains (approximately 1% the size of .com), and the zone transfer downloaded 920 MB of data in binary format, resulting in a 1.3 GB zone file in text format (that's *with* DNSSEC signatures – it's only 270 MB unsigned).

After configuring BIND 9 to host the `se` zone, it occupied 2 GB of RAM after loading all data into memory. This means that the `com` zone (with DNSSEC signatures) would proportionally require around 200 GB of memory.

From a comment, another similar question [over at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/1061258/113312) has someone obtaining the actual `com` zonefile through ICANN CZDS, and it was 22 GB in size (though it was not mentioned whether DNSSEC signatures were included or not, but it sounds like they weren't).

> Or is the authority for ".com" split among a few different servers?

This cannot be done with pure DNS, as NS records cannot be limited to specific subdomain ranges – they always delegate the entire hierarchy downwards.

(Without DNSSEC, it could be done in theory using a special-purpose DNS request proxy (similar to HTTP reverse proxies) which would forward requests to different authoritative servers, each responding to its own range of names. But with DNSSEC this looks like it would become *much* more complex, as "proof of non-existence" records would no longer work as intended.)

Every large zone does have multiple nameservers, but that's only for sharing the request load (and for redundancy) – they all have access to the same data.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense